# How to send data and a file to Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm having trouble sending both data and a file to Laravel and then validate them.

When working with with just the data, I can send it making a post request

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    axios.post(url, data).then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error', error);
    });
};
```

And then on my controller I can validate the data and work with it

```
public function create(Request $request) {
  $this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|max:20',
    'age' => 'required|numeric'
  ]);

  $data = $request->all();

  $name = $data['name'];
  $age = $data['age'];

  //Do some other stuff
}
```

This works fine, but if I want to upload an image and send it on the same request `$data['photo']` seems to be empty.

I tried sending the photo within a FormData, and appending the data as a string.

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(data));
    formData.append('photo', data.photo[0]);

    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url,
      data: formData
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error', error);
    });
};
```

This way I can get the image and work with it, but I'm not able to get the rest of the data correctly

```
public function create(Request $request) {
  $photo = $request->file('photo');

  // Do something with the photo

  // If I return $data I see on the console the object with all its data
  $data = $request->all()['data'];
  
  // But if I try to do something like this I get a 500 error
  $name = $data['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add each parameter individually to the formdata object, so you'll have to loop through `data` object and properties to formdata.

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    for (var property in data) {
        formData.append(property, data[property]);
    }
    formData.append('photo', data.photo[0]);

    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url,
      data: formData
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error', error);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you Musa, this solves the problem. I never thought of appending them individually.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass only data in formdata append function. just like

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('data', data);
    formData.append('photo', data.photo[0]);

    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url,
      data: formData
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error', error);
    });
};
```